# Screen touching event and button click

Tags: android, events, touch, move

I try to develop some kind of virtual joystick for a game. For controlling the camera i'm grabbing the screen coordinates through onTouchEvent and for controlling game's avatar i'm using buttons. To handle buttons i'm set setOnTouchListener. But, i can't touch the screen for moving camera and press the button at same time. Looks like onTouchEvent blocks other events.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the version of Is you build, because multi-touch has been implemented from see this http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=1007 it helps you to found of your device supports Multitouch

Comment: Thanks for answer and link. I want to build for API 11 and higher.

Comment: This can't be achieved using onTouchListener(), you will be required to override the onTouch() method. There is very good set tutorial for handling touch on this site, you can refer the same http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidTouch/article.html#multitouch

Comment: Thanks Rs9766. But this solution (and many others) are based on grab and compare screen coordinates with position of buttons or something like that. I can do that  but i'm afraid because devices with diferent screens and resolutions will have diferent coordenates.

Comment: Yeah It has to be done in that way, you can extend your view to be a ViewGroup and then add your button as child. now you can have the bound of the view and then override the onTouch and check whether the touch is in any bounds and then perform the action u want.This way your layout will support multiple resolution if you wanna see something like this check this https://github.com/r3gis3r/CSipSimple/blob/master/src/com/csipsimple/widgets/SlidingTab.java this is not multitouch but will give you idea how does extending a ViewGroup works